# Azure Data Warehouse Generate serial faster query

Tags: sql, etl, azure-synapse

Environment is Azure DW
I have a raw table like below;

```
ID   Start   End   Action        date
1     10     15    Processed     25-10-2019
2     55     105   In-Progress   21-10-2019
.....
```

I need to expand/transform the Start and End column so that they become serial number;

```
SN      Action        date
10      Processed     25-10-2019
11      Processed     25-10-2019
12      Processed     25-10-2019
13      Processed     25-10-2019
14      Processed     25-10-2019
.....
```

Azure Data Warehouse doesn't support recursive CTE or Cursor. So, have tried a while loop,

```sql
create table #temp_output (SerialNumber int not null, startSerialNumber int not null, endSerialNumber int not null);
insert into #temp_output select startSerialNumber, startSerialNumber, endSerialNumber from  dbo.raw
declare @rowcount int, @cnt int, @start int, @end int
set @cnt = 1
set @rowcount = (select count(*) from dbo.raw)
while @cnt <= @rowcount
begin
select top (@cnt) @start = startSerialNumber from dbo.raw
select top (@cnt) @end = endSerialNumber from dbo.raw
while @start <= @end
begin
       insert #temp_output
       select max(SerialNumber) + 1,
       startSerialNumber,
       endSerialNumber
       from #temp_output group by startSerialNumber, endSerialNumber having max(SerialNumber) < endSerialNumber
       set @start = @start + 1
       end
       set @cnt = @cnt + 1
       end
       select SerialNumber, startSerialNumber, endSerialNumber from #temp_output_delta order by SerialNumber
```

However this takes ages (6 hrs, when I cancelled the query) as the raw table has 50 million rows.

Need a better way to do this.

### Updated information 31-10-2019

Distribution for the source table is hash. 500 DWu . 
60 million row in source table. 
Average difference between start and end 3000.
The start can be 2million as well. 
No index on main table.
Column count 15
Clustered columnstore index on raw table.

Comment: Can you provide the DDL for the source table including the distribution (round robin or hash), datatypes and indexes please?  Also some more information about the data would be useful, eg what is the average difference between the start and end.  This will give an idea of what the expected number of rows you are expecting.  Say it’s 100 - turning 50 million rows into 500 million is a non-trivial operation.  What DWU are you running at?

Comment: Distribution for the source table is hash. 500 DWu . 60 million row in source table. Average difference between  start and end 3000. The start can be 2million as well. No index on main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is incomplete but you don't need a loop. You can join it to a tally table using `BETWEEN`

If you have a tally table (which is a table that simply has number from 1 to... 1 million in it)

```
 SELECT T.TallyNumber As SN, E.Action, E.Date
 FROM YourTable E
 INNER JOIN TallyTable As T
 ON T.TallyNumber BETWEEN E.Start AND E.End
```

Since you are loading this into a new table, you should use CTAS

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable]
WITH
(
 DISTRIBUTION = HASH([Start])
 ,CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
 SELECT T.TallyNumber As SN, E.Action, E.Date
 FROM YourTable E
 INNER JOIN TallyTable As T
 ON T.TallyNumber BETWEEN E.[Start] AND E.[End];
```

Note there is a whole lot of design around `DISTRIBUTION`. You need to get this right for performance. The above statement is just an example. You should probably use a different hash.

You need to get the distribution of the two source tables as well as the distribution of the target table right for good performance.

Comment: This is working , however is still slow on the 50 million rows.

Comment: Is it _slower_ though? I assume it's faster. There's really no point assessing performance on words like "slow", you need solid metrics, like how long does it actually take? Also, I expect it would be quicker if YourTable and TallyTable are optimally colocated. You mention above that the distribution is hash but this doesn't mean anything without knowing what columns feed the hash. Also are you using `CTAS` for this? These are two SQLDW performance concepts that you really should understand.

Comment: I have added some comments to my answer. You should really understand CTAS and Distribution properly